# How to define dynamic number of columns in django-datatables-view

Tags: django, datatables, django-datatable

I'm using the django-datatables-view (that is used in conjunction with the jQuery plugin DataTables). For normal use, I create a class-based view based on BaseDatatableView and define there the columns variable:

```
class MyCBV(LoginRequiredMixin, BaseDatatableView):
    model = myModel
    columns = ['my_model_column1','my_model_column2']
    ...
```

Now I would like to create a *variable* number of columns that is based on a parameter. I can access the parameter in the CBV *functions* but it seems I cannot overwrite the columns variable. For example, I tried to overwrite the columns variable in get_context_data function but columns retains its original value later in render_column function.

Somebody has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseDatatableView` implements `DatatableMixin` which has a method `get_columns` with a default implementation of

```
def get_columns(self):
    """ Returns the list of columns that are returned in the result set
    """
    return self.columns
```

You can override it and pass your custom columns here (using your parameter)